# How to read hdf5 file or mat v7.3 in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hdf5

The training data is stored in the .mat -v7.3 file. The file path is gs://bucket/train. How to load this file in my Google Cloud machine learning engine or Google Cloud datalab notebook?